# Swift Optional Value in variable

Tags: ios, swift, variables, optional-values

I have some variables all coming true just `tarih1` output shows 
`Optional(2016)`. I didn't resolve it. I want to fix it to `2016`.

My code below.

```
if let myString: String = String(seans.SeanceDate) {
    let myStringArrf = myString.componentsSeparatedByString("T")
    let tarih: NSString =  myStringArrf[0]
    let saat: String =  String(myStringArrf[1])
    let myStringArrf2 = saat.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
    let saat1: String = myStringArrf2[0]
    let saat2: String = myStringArrf2[1]

    cell.saat.text = "\(saat1):\(saat2)"
    cell.saat2.text = "\(saat1):\(saat2)"

    let myStringArrf23 = tarih.componentsSeparatedByString("-")
    let tarih1: NSString = myStringArrf23[0]
    let tarih2: NSString = myStringArrf23[1]
    let tarih3: NSString = myStringArrf23[2]

    let sontarih: String = ("\(tarih3)-\(tarih2)-\(tarih1)")
    cell.tarih.text = sontarih

    print(sontarih)
}
```

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: @Dravidian tarih1 , showing Optional(2016) i want to fix it to 2016  TY

Comment: Use : `print(tarih1!)`

Comment: @MidhunMP Says delete ! characters

Comment: What does `print(myString)` output?

Comment: @OOPer Mystring = Optional("2016-08-21T21:15:00")

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do?  This is looking like quite a bit of an [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/244435).  What is the type of `seans.SeanceDate`?  What does it return?  And do you have a custom `String` initializer for it, whatever it's type is?

Comment: Then try changing the first line to `if let myString: String = String(seans.SeanceDate!) {`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use optional binding to find out whether an optional contains a value, and if so, to make that
value available as a temporary constant or variable. Optional binding can be used with if and while
statements to check for a value inside an optional, and to extract that value into a constant or variable,
as part of a single action

```
if let constantName = someOptional {
    // statements
}

if let tarih1 = myStringArrf23[0]{
    print(tarih1)
}
```

Comment: Gives red !  Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'